# How to exclude some domains from a URL pattern?

Tags: php, url, pattern-matching

I'm trying to fetch online vedio and its descriptions. youtube and several others that provides api accesses work fine. For the rest of website, I will use oEmbed. 
So, for youtube, if pattern match this:

```
/^http:\/\/(www\.)?youtube.com\/watch/
```

then, it will use "yt custom service" to fetch content.

For the rest of the site, will use oEmbed service:

```
preg_match_all('`.*?((http|https)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i', $content, $matches);
```

So, how can I exclude youtube and several others from this match_all pattern?

Comment: Why don't you just not run the code at all when it's a YouTube URL? `if (strpos($url, 'youtube.com') === false) preg_match_all...`

Answer (score 0):

As @Dan said the best way is using an if sentence, other way to write it is:

```
if (strpos($url, 'youtube.com')===false) {
// use "yt custom service"
} else {
// use "oEmbed"
}
```

I suggest to avoid regex when there are not necessary. They sometimes only add complexity.